# This room sql not query my data for db,What should I write

Tags: android-room

```sql
@Query("select * from pinyin_wl where pinyin in (:pinyinLikes) order by pinyin_length asc, count desc , base_count desc limit 1")   
fun queryPinyinByLikeFirst( pinyinLikes:List<String>):List<PinYinData>
```

How do I write this sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is fine, as is the function. **The following demonstrates**.

First  the **PinYinData** `@Entity` annotated class (assumed, but based upon the available information provided in the question):-

```
@Entity(tableName = "pinyin_wl")
data class PinYinData(
    @PrimaryKey
    val pinyin: String,
    val pinyin_length: Int,
    val count: Int,
    val base_count: Int
)
```

The `@Dao` annotated interface:-

```
@Dao
interface TheDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(pinYinData: PinYinData)
    @Query("select * from pinyin_wl where pinyin in (:pinyinLikes) order by pinyin_length asc, count desc , base_count desc limit 1")
    fun queryPinyinByLikeFirst( pinyinLikes:List<String>):List<PinYinData>
}
```

- i.e. your function and another to insert some data

To actually test some activity code (note for brevity run on the main thread):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: TheDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getTheDao()
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "a", pinyin_length = 10, count = 100, base_count = 100))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "b", pinyin_length = 20, count = 200, base_count = 200))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "c", pinyin_length = 30, count = 300, base_count = 300))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "x", pinyin_length = 40, count = 400, base_count = 400))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "y", pinyin_length = 50, count = 500, base_count = 500))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "z", pinyin_length = 60, count = 600, base_count = 600))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "m", pinyin_length = 70, count = 700, base_count = 700))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "n", pinyin_length = 80, count = 800, base_count = 800))
        dao.insert(PinYinData(pinyin = "o", pinyin_length = 90, count = 900, base_count = 900))
        for (sp in dao.queryPinyinByLikeFirst(arrayListOf("x","y","z"))) {
            Log.d("DBINFO_A","PINYIN is ${sp.pinyin} LEN is ${sp.pinyin_length} COUNT is ${sp.count} BASECOUNT is ${sp.base_count}")
        }
    }
}
```

- i.e. data is inserted and then your query is invoked

When the above is run then the log includes:-

```
D/DBINFO_A: PINYIN is x LEN is 40 COUNT is 400 BASECOUNT is 400
```

i.e. pinyin **x** has been extracted as it was the first of the 3 rows.

With a subtle change to the SQL as per:-

```
@Query("select * from pinyin_wl where pinyin /*>>>>>>>>>>>*/ NOT /*<<<<<<<<<<*/  in (:pinyinLikes) order by pinyin_length asc, count desc , base_count desc /*>>>>>>>>>> limit 1 <<<<<<<<<<*/")
```

- i.e. **`NOT`** has been added to exclude rows that match the passed list, and
- the LIMIT 1 has been commented out so all extracted rows are output

The result, using the same data, now becomes:-

```
D/DBINFO_A: PINYIN is a LEN is 10 COUNT is 100 BASECOUNT is 100
D/DBINFO_A: PINYIN is b LEN is 20 COUNT is 200 BASECOUNT is 200
D/DBINFO_A: PINYIN is c LEN is 30 COUNT is 300 BASECOUNT is 300
D/DBINFO_A: PINYIN is m LEN is 70 COUNT is 700 BASECOUNT is 700
D/DBINFO_A: PINYIN is n LEN is 80 COUNT is 800 BASECOUNT is 800
D/DBINFO_A: PINYIN is o LEN is 90 COUNT is 900 BASECOUNT is 900
```

- i.e. x, y and z are not extracted.